# IllegalStateException on ServletRequest getAsyncContext()

Tags: java, servlets, junit, jetty

I'm trying to create a test for Java Servlet. For test I choose embedded Jetty server. It's my test case:

```java
    Server server;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() throws Exception {
        this.server = new Server(8080);
        ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler();
        final ServletHolder holder = new ServletHolder(new GenericServlet() {
            @Override
            public void service(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse) {
                final AsyncContext asyncContext = servletRequest.getAsyncContext(); // <- exception on this line
                // the code below is just to verify the test is working with embedded jetty server
                Executors.newCachedThreadPool().submit(
                        () -> {
                            try {
                                asyncContext.getResponse().getWriter().println("Hello");
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
                            } finally {
                                asyncContext.complete();
                            }
                        }
                );
            }
        });
        holder.setAsyncSupported(true);
        context.addServlet(holder, "/");
        server.setHandler(context);
        server.start();
    }

    @AfterEach
    void tearDown() throws Exception{
        server.stop();
        target = null;
    }
```

I added some code to verify the server is started correctly and supports `AsyncContext`. (I enabled with `holder.setAsyncSupported(true);`).

To check it I added a test:

```java
    @Test
    void jettyTest() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        final String text = "Hello";
        final String body = HttpClient.newHttpClient()
                .send(HttpRequest.newBuilder().GET().uri(URI.create("http://localhost:8080/")).build(), HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString()).body();
        MatcherAssert.assertThat(body, Matchers.equalTo(text));
    }
```

But the handler crashes on `getAsyncContext()` call:

```
[main] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - jetty-10.0.0; built: 2020-12-02T21:06:43.949Z; git: b9645a17373e4e9b7f30b6c0a07defcea2cb660b; jvm 13.0.1+9
[main] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler - Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@33c911a1{/,null,AVAILABLE}
[main] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector - Started ServerConnector@647e447{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8080}
[main] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - Started Server@4218d6a3{STARTING}[10.0.0,sto=0] @1778ms
[qtp1014166943-22] WARN org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel - /
java.lang.IllegalStateException: s=HANDLING rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getAsyncContext(Request.java:606)
    at com.example.servlettest.JettyTest$1.service(JettyTest.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:761)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:517)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1358)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:181)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:472)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1282)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$0(HttpChannel.java:404)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:661)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:396)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SocketChannelEndPoint$1.run(SocketChannelEndPoint.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:912)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
[main] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - Stopped Server@4218d6a3{STOPPING}[10.0.0,sto=0]
[main] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector - Stopped ServerConnector@647e447{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8080}
[main] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler - Stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@33c911a1{/,null,STOPPED}
```

What could be the problem with my code? I tried to run it without using `AsyncContext` and it's working fine. But my real servlet (not this one from minimal reproducing example) depends on `AsyncContext`:

```java
        final ServletHolder holder = new ServletHolder(new GenericServlet() {
            @Override
            public void service(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse) throws IOException {
                servletResponse.getWriter().println("Hello"); // <- working fine
        });
``
```

Comment: Is this the complete code?  I don't see the startAsync call?

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt yes, sorry, it was my foolish mistake. Forgot to add `startAsync` in the test

Comment: I strongly recommend to lookup "web sockets" instead of trying to reinvent it. It's already natively supported by Jetty since 9.1.0.

Comment: @Kirill was the lack of startAsync the problem? is it working for you now?

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt yes, adding `startAsync` fixed the test